# Using Django-filter with DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to use django-filter with DRF.

I am trying to do the integration with DRF documented here:

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html

Here is my view class:

```
class PageView(APIView):
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category', 'start_date', "end_date", "limit")

    def get(self, request):
        page_saves = Page.objects.all()
        serializer = PageSerializer(page_saves, many=True)
        return Response({"pages": serializer.data})
```

However I feel I must be missing something - nothing is filtering.

Do I need a filter like this:

```
class PageFilter(filters.FilterSet):
```

with some logic in it?

I'm just not entirely sure how to get filtering to work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `self.filter_queryset` otherwise it won't use the class in `filter_backend` (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/559088463b8625880e6a03dde804cb5a61da3088/rest_framework/generics.py#L140)

Consider doing the following:

```
from rest_framework import generics
class PageView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('category', 'start_date', "end_date", "limit")

    def get(self, request):
        page_saves = self.filter_queryset(Page.objects.all())
        serializer = PageSerializer(page_saves, many=True)
        return Response({"pages": serializer.data})
```

The example in django-filter documentation uses the ListAPIView, which calls `self.filter_queryset` inside its `get` implementation.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'PageView' object has no attribute 'filter_queryset' - do I need to pass in some other class for PageView to inherit from maybe?

Comment: Try inheriting from `GenericAPIView` https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/5828d8f7ca167b11296733a2b54f9d6fca29b7b0/rest_framework/generics.py#L24

Comment: TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: c, a, t, e, g, o, r, y

I feel like query filters should not be this difficult to implement.

Comment: You have to apparently use a list arg if you're only using one value:

filter_fields = (['category'])

I temporarily removed the others for testing.

If you have multiple values though, the list is unnecessary:

filter_fields = ('category', 'date')

Comment: Try `('category',)`.  Without trailing comma ('category') is evaluated as string.